# Replace string for specific key in multilevel Javascript array

Tags: javascript

As the title mention, I want to replace the values of a particular key in a javascript object.

Sample Array -

```
[{
    title: "stackflow",
    child: [{
        title: 'stack',
        child: [{
            title: 'javascript stack',
            child: [{
                title: 'stack node',
                child: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Value to be replaced `key` is `title` and value `stack` with `stackoverflow` anywhere in the array.

I already google and tried many solutions but didn't get the proper solution for this. Any reference link or solution most welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to iterate over your object, checking the `title` keys and then, if the value is "stack", replace it with "stackoverflow"?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map and a recursive function:

```js
const oldItems = [{
  title: "stackflow",
  child: [{
    title: 'stack',
    child: [{
      title: 'javascript stack',
      child: [{
        title: 'stack node',
        child: []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

const replace = (items) =>
  items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    title: item.title === 'stack' ? 'stackoverflow' : item.title,
    child: replace(item.child)
  }));

const newItems = replace(oldItems);
console.log(newItems);
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/romilton/yrkg7ndL/9/)

And if you want to replace all instances of `stack` - *including those that sit inside longer strings* - then change the following line:

`title: item.title === 'stack' ? 'stackoverflow' : item.title,`

to:

`title: item.title.replaceAll('stack', 'stackoverflow'),`

Comment: Nice answer. Stack Overflow allows you to embed runnable code snippets using the [<>] button, I've added one in for you

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution, probably the performance is poor against other solutions.

```
const array = [{
    title: "stackflow",
    child: [{
        title: 'stack',
        child: [{
            title: 'javascript stack',
            child: [{
                title: 'stackoverflow stack',
                child: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array).replace(/"title":"stack"/g,'"title":"stackoverflow"'))
```

Comment: This is a pretty smart and clean way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function.

Updated the answer to replace all the exact `stack` string.

```js
const array = [{
    title: "stackflow",
    child: [{
        title: 'stack',
        child: [{
            title: 'javascript stack',
            child: [{
                title: 'stackoverflow stack',
                child: []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]

const replaceAllOccurs = (arr) => (
    arr.map(({ title, child }) => (
        {
            title: title.replace(/\bstack\b/g, 'stackoverflow'),
            child: replaceAllOccurs(child)
        }
    ))
)

console.log(replaceAllOccurs(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

@RoMilton has a good answer, but just wanted to contribute with another option for dynamic values:

```js
const sampleObj = [{
  title: "stackflow",
  child: [{
      title: 'stack',
      child: [{
          title: 'javascript stack',
          child: [{
              title: 'stack node',
              child: []
          }]
      }]
  }]
}]

const findAndReplace = (obj, key, value, newValue) => {
  return obj.map((item) => {
    if (item[key] === value) {
      return {
        ...item,
        [key]: newValue,
      }
    } else {
      const objKeys = Object.keys(item)
      const arrayKey = objKeys.find((key) => Array.isArray(item[key]))
      return {
        ...item,
        [arrayKey]: findAndReplace(item[arrayKey], key, value, newValue)
      }
    }
  })
}

const updatedObj = findAndReplace(sampleObj, 'title', 'stack', 'stackoverflow')
console.log(updatedObj)
```